# Query for find the list of DISCRETE DECADE with the number of records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database including the following tables:

> ACTOR (id, fname, lname, gender)
> MOVIE (id, name, year, rank)
> DIRECTOR (id, fname, lname)
> CAST (a_id, m_id, role)
> MOVIE_DIRECTOR (d_id, m_id)

Now I want to retrieve the data of the following question.

> A decade is a sequence of 10 consecutive years. For example, 1965,1966,..., 1974 is a decade, and so is 1967, 1968,...,1976. Find the decade with the largest number of films.
> **The Decades must be unique, like we can't have a Decade 1965-1974 and than 1966-1975 etc.**

This Exact Question was already asked before, and I got two queries, but these doesn't give DISTINCT decades. These queries had decade 1995-2004, than 1996-2005, 1994-2003. It calculated decade for each year.

```
select y.year as decade_start, y.year + 9 as decade_end,
       count(*) as num_movies
from (select distinct year from movies) y join
     movies m
     on m.year >= y.year and m.year < y.year + 10
group by y.year
order by count(*) desc;
```

> By Gordon Linoff

The Other was

```
WITH MOV AS
(
   SELECT year as movie_year, COUNT(id) as total_movies
   FROM MOVIE 
   GROUP BY year
)
SELECT
  m1.movie_year as decade_start,
  MAX(m2.movie_year) as decade_end,
  SUM(m2.total_movies) as total_movies
FROM MOV m1
LEFT JOIN MOV m2 ON (m2.movie_year BETWEEN m1.movie_year AND m1.movie_year + 9)
GROUP BY m1.movie_year
ORDER BY SUM(m2.total_movies) DESC
```

> By LukStorms

*Also, a very very interesting find which I got when I ran both the queries in MySQL workbench is, that the 1st one by Gordon took 15+ seconds to run, where as the one by LukStorm took under a second to run.
Can any one point out why there is such a difference in time for both queries?*

Sample Data of MOVIES table:

```
+--------+--------------------------------------+------+-----------+
| id     | name                                 | year | rankscore |
+--------+--------------------------------------+------+-----------+
| 282455 | Roundhay Garden Scene                | 1888 |      NULL |
| 337409 | Traffic Crossing Leeds Bridge        | 1888 |      NULL |
| 218187 | Monkeyshines, No. 2                  | 1890 |      NULL |
| 218186 | Monkeyshines, No. 1                  | 1890 |       7.3 |
| 218188 | Monkeyshines, No. 3                  | 1890 |      NULL |
|  95175 | Duncan Smoking                       | 1891 |       3.6 |
| 230974 | Newark Athlete                       | 1891 |       4.3 |
|  95174 | Duncan or Devonald with Muslin Cloud | 1891 |       3.5 |
| 218116 | Monkey and Another, Boxing           | 1891 |       3.2 |
|  95171 | Duncan and Another, Blacksmith Shop  | 1891 |       3.5 |
+--------+--------------------------------------+------+-----------+
```

Comment: So from where to start the decade? 1970 - 1979 or 1965-1974? How will query know this? Please add some sample data and expected output.

Comment: "Find the decade with the largest number of films.
The Decades must be unique, like we can't have a Decade 1965-1974 and than 1966-1975 etc." makes no sense; if you are looking for the decade with the largest number, you don't care if some decade with a lower count overlapped or not.  Do you want to find the highest decade, then look for a second highest excluding any that overlap with that, and a third highest excluding any that overlap with the first two, etc?  That would be kind of odd.

Comment: or do you want to find the highest decade (e.g. 1995-2004) then rank other decades that match that (1985-1994, 1975-1984, ..., 2005-2014, 2015-2024, ...)?

Comment: or do you just want to pick some arbitrary rule (e.g. only decades whose first year ends with 0) to make discrete decades?  tell us how you expect it to work.

Comment: My bad, I should have given sample data.
The movies table has id, name and year columns.

So we need to find the first year(least value of year), in the data it's 1888.
So the decade will start from 1888-1897, 1898-1907, 1908-1918.....1998-2007.

Answer (score 0):

(Answering your question about the difference in time)

The second query takes advantage of a common table expression to efficiently categorize the count of movies by year before counting decades.  This requires mysql 8 or mariadb 10.2+.

Answer (score 0):

The first query does one aggregation on the full table and then multiplies the data by about 10 (the number of years in a decade) and does another aggregation.

The second query can be executed in various ways.  But given that it is more efficient, it is probably doing:

- Aggregating the full data by year.
- Doing a self join on the aggregated data, which is significantly reduced in size.
- Aggregating again.

This will be faster assuming that there are a fair number of years and many movies per year.

Importantly, my answer will work in pre 8.0 versions of MySQL.  If you want an efficient version in MySQL 8+, then the following should be faster than either:

```
select m.year as decade_start, m.year + 9 as decade_end,
       count(*) as num_movies_in_year,
       sum(count(*)) over (order by y.year range between current row and 9 rows following) as num_movies_in_decade
from movies m
group by m.year;
```

Note:  This assumes that you have movies in every year.  If not, then you can easily use a `range` partition instead.

I assume the original answer was old enough that MySQL did not support window functions or that it was explicitly on an older version of MySQL.